# How to perform Pagination in Azure Data Factory with Query Parameter

Tags: azure, rest, pagination, azure-data-factory

I'm attempting to retrieve data from the Typeform API, which by default can only return 1000 responses. To surpass this limit and obtain more than 1000 responses, it's necessary to send an API request with the before/after parameter along with a token.

The API request looks like this:

``` https://api.typeform.com/forms/Na5du3oD/responses?page_size=1000&after``<token> ```
Here, the token is the identifier for the specific set of responses you want.

In the context of Azure ADF, pagination can be implemented, but the challenge lies in the fact that the token is present in the request body.

The API response structure is as follows:

```
{
    items: [
        {
            'token': <token>
        }
    ]
}
```

`URL: <hostname>/forms/Na5du3oD/responses?page_size=1000&after={offset}`

Now, there are two issues to address:

If using query parameter pagination, the body can be utilized to set the offset value. However, since the token is part of a nested array, setting the value as $.items[0]['token'] becomes a challenge, and passing this as the body is not feasible.

The token value is obtained as a response from the API, so how can an empty value be passed as the offset?

Seeking guidance on how to achieve this or any potential workarounds. Your assistance is highly appreciated.

I tried to response by using Query Parameter with value $.items[0]['token']. But ADF is not supporting it!

Answer (score 0):

> The token value is obtained as a response from the API, so how can an empty value be passed as the offset?

***As far as I know, your pagination issues are due to the value cannot be obtained until the first answer.***

[image]

In the queryparameter rule, the { } around {after} tell it to look in dataset or linked service for a place to substitute. If we exclude the { } and use  `after`  , it should, to my understanding, add next to the query parameter string once the value can be filled. Since you are using body, it won't be filled until the second call.

**Also see:** [Help with REST api pagination rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1107042/help-with-rest-api-pagination-rules)